# Creating new JSONObject from String Returns Null - JAVA / Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm attempting to create a new JSONObject from a String however for some reason the new JSONObject is always null - and I'm unsure why.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Source:

```
JSONObject messagesObj;


    String mArr = intent.getStringExtra("msgArr");

            try {
                if (mArr != null)
                    messagesObj = new JSONObject(mArr);

                if (messagesObj != null)
                    populateMessages(messagesObj);
                DataManager.clientChatMarkMessagesSeen(chatId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            //    DataManager.clientChatLoad(this);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

### Values:

```
String mArr = [{"message":"User has joined the chat.","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:35:09","name":"User"},{"message":"Hello World?","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:35:17","name":"User"},{"message":"User has left the chat.","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:38:40","name":"User"}]
```

Comment: It's not a JSONObject though, it's a JSONArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that isn't a json object-  its a JSONArray.  Try creating a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

The string is json array not object..please see the root node it is  not {}

Modify the string like this array of objects

String mArr = {"results": [{"message":"User has joined the chat.","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:35:09","name":"User"},{"message":"Hello World?","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:35:17","name":"User"},{"message":"User has left the chat.","type":"agent","created":"2016-12-07 17:38:40","name":"User"}]}

Answer (score -1):

Use JSONArray array = new JSONArray("string here"). It's an array if it starts with square brackets.